# cvs2svn for only one revision

Tags: svn, cvs

I have a CVS module called myModule and it has a number of revisions. So when I want to work on that project I do `cvs co myModule -r myRev`. I need to move this revision only to SVN. I do not how to specify that in the conf file nor on the command line.

Anyone knows how that is done?

Comment: I can use the command line not using the conf file but I am not sure what to pass for CVSPATH. My CVSROOT is :pserver:user@host:2401/srv/cvs/vegasroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to move a single revision, you don't seem to be concerned with history.  Are you concerned with preserving changeset author?  If not you can skip cvs2svn entirely and do a {{cvs export myModule -r myRev}} and then check that into svn.
I personally couldn't do this.  I'm too anal about the history.   But if you're OK without the history, this may be a good deal for you.

I'd run cvs2svn to create a dump file, and then use [svn dump filter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) to include only the revision I wanted.  In your case you may want the svn revision on the trunk and the revision where it was tagged.  Alternatively you can simply tag that revision once you import it into your svn repo.